# Weird IIS7 http redirection behavior

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7

I have a web server running Windows Server 2008 with IIS7. I have a bunch of websites which are all bound to the same IP address, but with different host header values. Most of the host headers are something like www.sitename.com.

I also have a corresponding website entry for each which listens for the host "sitename.com" and does a redirect to "www.sitename.com" within IIS7 (to cater for non-www requests). Now this is all pretty straight forward, but I've noticed the when setting up the Http Redirection, some wierd things happen:

Firstly, the "redirect" website entries must be pointed at a different physical directory than the site it's trying to redirect to, otherwise the redirection settings get set for *both* sites at once.

Secondly, sometimes whilst setting up Http Redirection on an individual site, Http Redirection gets set at a **server** level, and **all** sites start redirecting to that one URL.

How does this happen? Under what circumstances could setting Http Redirection on an *individual* site affect *all* sites? This is scary!!!

Comment: I think we really need more information regarding your setup and IIS Rewrite rules to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point each of the websites to different physical location so that `Http Redirection` module can make a `webconfig` file for each of them.